# Simple code, app has stopped working

Tags: assembly, fasm

I start to learn asm using fasm, unfortunately after compile code below I get error: "app has stopped working", I use Win7 64bit. Has anybody any idea why it doesn't work?

```
format PE Console 4.0
include 'win32a.inc'

push MB_OK
push _tresc
push _tytul
push 0
call [MessageBoxA]

push 0
call [ExitProcess]

mov eax,0
ret

_tytul  db "Tytul",0
_tresc  db "Hello world :)",0

data import
    library user32,'USER32.DLL'
    library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL'
    import user32,\
        MessageBoxA,'MessageBoxA'
    import kernel32,\
        ExitProcess,'ExitProcess'
end data
```

Comment: This is not the error, but if `_tytul` shall be the title of your window, you've to swap `push _tytul` and `push _tresc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be only one **library** macro invocation. Your **ExitProcess** does not get imported and calls the wrong address. Put everything in one **library** invocation:

```
data import
    library user32,'USER32.DLL',kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL'
    import user32,MessageBoxA,'MessageBoxA'
    import kernel32,ExitProcess,'ExitProcess'
end data
```